# Old Ask Ubuntu account

Tags: support, user-accounts

I used to participate on AskUbuntu.com as the user:3419.  Unforunately, the domain in which I have had previously used for that account is no longer in existence.  I am not sure how to recover it or the launchpad id from then.  I was using the passwordcard method to keep up with everything and that system turned out to be a failure for me.

My question is:  Is there a way to my old account or reset it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've merged your old account in to your new one. This will carry over your reputation, questions, bounties, statistics, etc.

Comment: Thank you Marco.